# Можно ли использовать selenium в телеграм боте на сервере

Tags: python, telegram-bot, selenium, веб-сервер, aiogram

У меня есть бот на python, написанный на библиотеке aiogram, и в этом боте используется библиотека selenium. Сейчас мне необходимо выложить этого телеграм бота на сервер. Вопрос в следующем, насколько сложно это сделать, ведь для selenium необходимо установить драйвер geckodriver. Может кто-нибудь сможет подсказать, как это сделать правильно, и какой вообще хостинг для этого лучше использовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полагаю для теста подойдет бесплатный Heroku. Вот более детальная [статья по установке geckodriver на Heroku](https://pyronlaboratory.github.io/heroku-integrated-firefox-geckodriver/)
Если есть другой VPS/VDS с linux, то еще проще - глянь как установить на линукс

Answer (score 0):

geckodriver для Linux можно взять [с официального Github](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver).
Готовые бинарники смотрите в releases.